# VB.NET Search Text File for Customer Number and display entire customer record in listbox

Tags: vb.net

I am new to Visual Basic 2010 and have been banging my head against the wall with this one.

I have a form that accepts user input and saves it to a text file in the following format:

"Customer #:" 00

Doe, John

10350 Some Street

City, State Zip Code

Telephone Number

"Account Balance: $" 00.00

"Date Of Last Payment:" Month/Day/Year

I have a text box where the user inputs either a customer number or last name depending upon which check box is checked. The purpose of this is to search the text file for a customer record by last name or customer number.

When Searched I would like  the customer with the last name or customer number 
used in the search displayed in a listbox.

Here is the code I have below:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles btnSearch.Click
    'Local Variables

    Dim ReadCustomerRecords As StreamReader
    Dim strCustomerNumber As String

    ' Validate Search Criteria
    If chkCustomerNumber.Checked = False And chkLastName.Checked = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select either Customer Number OR Last Name" & vbNewLine   & "to narrow your search.", "Attention")

    End If
    If chkCustomerNumber.Checked And chkLastName.Checked Then
        MessageBox.Show("You may only search by Customer Number OR Last Name." & vbNewLine & "Please revise your search.", "Attention")
    End If

    If chkCustomerNumber.Checked Then
        ReadCustomerRecords = File.OpenText(strCustomerRecordsFile)
        strCustomerNumber = ReadCustomerRecords.ReadLine()
        Do Until strCustomerRecordsFile.Contains(txtSearchFile.Text)

            If strCustomerNumber.Contains(txtSearchFile.Text) Then
                lstCustomerSearch.Items.Add(strCustomerNumber)
                lstCustomerSearch.Items.Add(ReadCustomerRecords.ReadLine())
                lstCustomerSearch.Items.Add(ReadCustomerRecords.ReadLine())
                lstCustomerSearch.Items.Add(ReadCustomerRecords.ReadLine())
                lstCustomerSearch.Items.Add(ReadCustomerRecords.ReadLine())
                lstCustomerSearch.Items.Add(ReadCustomerRecords.ReadLine())
                lstCustomerSearch.Items.Add(ReadCustomerRecords.ReadLine())
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("The customer number you entered is not valid." & vbNewLine & "Please try again or search by Last Name.", "Attention")
            End If
            Return
        Loop
        ReadCustomerRecords.Close()
    End If

    If chkLastName.Checked Then
        ReadCustomerRecords = File.OpenText(strCustomerRecordsFile)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I had meant to add that when I run the application, select Customer Number Check box, and search "01" , it displays Customer 01's record

Comment: But when I try 02 and so on it just locks up. I know I have it all wrong so can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition in this:

```
Do Until strCustomerRecordsFile.Contains(txtSearchFile.Text)
```

Is likely causing your loop not to terminate properly as it means until the name of the file contains the search term, do the code which is inside the loop. Since the name of the file never changes, your loop is likely not terminating properly.

With regards to searching the text file, you could do something instead like:

```
If chkCustomerNumber.Checked Then
    Dim custRecords() as String = File.ReadAllLines(strCustomerRecordsFile)
    Dim isRecordFound as Boolean = false

    For i As Integer = 0 To custRecords.Length - 1
         If custRec(i).Contains(txtSearchFile.Text) Then
             isRecordFound = true;

             lstCustomerSearch.Items.Add(custRec(i))
             lstCustomerSearch.Items.Add(custRec(i + 1))
             lstCustomerSearch.Items.Add(custRec(i + 2))
             lstCustomerSearch.Items.Add(custRec(i + 3))
             lstCustomerSearch.Items.Add(custRec(i + 4))
             lstCustomerSearch.Items.Add(custRec(i + 5))
             lstCustomerSearch.Items.Add(custRec(i + 6))

             Exit For
         End If            
    Next

    If Not isRecordFound Then
         MessageBox.Show("The customer number you entered is not valid." & vbNewLine & "Please try again or search by Last Name.", "Attention")
    End If
End If
```

So it's a little different but:

1. We use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) to read all the lines in your text file into an array of strings (each array element is one line). You could still use `StreamReader` like you are doing, but for simplicity the example uses `File.ReadAllLines`
2. Once we have the contents of your file, we can loop through and find the relevant customer ID (see below for a comment about this)
3. Once we have found the customer ID we replicate what you were doing with reading the next lines via the `StreamReader` with looking at the next elements in the array (noting that each array element is a file line)...A defensiveness check for you to implement here would be that we are trying to "look ahead" in the array by a number of elements but if there aren't that many elements left in the array you'll get an exception about the index being out of bounds
4. We can `Exit For` from the loop after a record has been found because it's a bit pointless to proceed any further

**PS.** For your file format an alternative for you to consider is to have an entire record on one line and delimited (e.g. you could use a "|" or something like that to separate records) instead of on multiple lines.

**PPS.** Be careful with using the `Contains` clause for searching because "02" would also match an address like "1002 Fake Street" instead of an ID you are looking for so you might dredge up false positives. Tweaking your file format should help you get around this.

Comment: You are a life saver. I mean that literally. I have been working on this section for nearly two days and my frustration level had hit its peak. I changed the code to better suit my program but one thing I did change was the .contain(txtSearchfile.Text) to .Contain(""& txtSearchFile.txt)